# how to increases java variable value in JavaScript code in JSP

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#selecctall").change(function(){
                 <% int j =0; %>
                 var current = 0;
            $.each($("input[name='deferral']"),function(){
               if($('#deferral'+current).is(':checked')){
                current++;
                 <% j ++; %>
                alert(<%= j %>);
               }else{
                $('#deferral'+current).prop('checked', true);
               <%if(j< rowid.size()){%> 
                function($(this).val(),'<%= (String)vendor.get(j)%>','<%= (String)invoice.get(j)%>', current)
               alert(<%= j %>);
               <%}%>
                current++;
                  <% j ++; %>
                }
            });  
        });  
    });                                 
</script>
```

In above code I tried to increase the value of 'j' but it is not increasing.

otherwise I want to "(String)vendor.get(j)" this function should accept JavaScript variable i.e. 'current',but how can I convert 'current' JavaScript variable into java integer

Comment: Java: server. JavaScript: client (in this case). This is a mish-mosh of concerns; please consider a different approach that's easier to read, maintain, and think about.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot put java coding inside javascript can yos add a more information about j where is j is coming from the i will help you
this would be some thing like this firs you have to get the value of j then increment it

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#selecctall").change(function(){
             var j=$('#from some where').val();// you have to get the value of j from somewhere 
j++;//them increment it
             var current = 0;
        $.each($("input[name='deferral']"),function(){
           if($('#deferral'+current).is(':checked')){
            current++;
             <% j ++; %>
            alert(<%= j %>);
           }else{
            $('#deferral'+current).prop('checked', true);
           <%if(j< rowid.size()){%> 
            function($(this).val(),'<%= (String)vendor.get(j)%>','<%=   (String)invoice.get(j)%>', current)
           alert(<%= j %>);
           <%}%>
            current++;
              <% j ++; %>
            }
        });  
    });  
});                                 
</script>
```

Comment: I already have 'current' JavaScript variable, how can assign or use JavaScript variable value in java

Comment: see javascript and java are two diffrent thing we cant mix there codings meant to say we cant write java coading(<%some code %>) in side <script></script> tag